# Calculate a maximum amount of $ payout in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to calculate a percentage payout with the condition that it does not go above an amount; i.e., 50% up to $8,000 for a maximum payable of $4,000.

This would be applied consistently so if the number is say $9,000 or $10,000 the maximum payout will still remain a maximum of $4,000 but if the number is $7,000 the payout is $3,500.

Comment: Assuming your number is in A2, you can do =MIN(A2*.5, 4000)

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you want to do this with varying amounts and percentages.

Say your Amounts start in A2, Percentages in B2, and Payout to be calculated in D2.  If the maximum is fixed at $4000, type this in D2 and fill down:

```
=IF(A2*B2>4000,4000,A2*B2
```

If the maximum can vary, put it in column C, and change the formula to this:

```
=IF(A2*B2>C2,C2,A2*B2)
```

Columns A,C and D should be formatted as currency.  Column B as a percentage.